# How to select the number in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which values is of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` type. It has following structure:

> "Key1=Value1-Key2=Value2-...Key_N=Value_N"

For eg:

**"Type=A-SRID=152-WOID=3"**

Here it has 3 key-value pairs: `{Type: A, SRID: 152, WOID: 3}`

What I am trying to do is to extract the value of key named **"SRID"**, it may OR may not exist in the string. If it exists, its value also exists and must be integer.

So using the example string above, "**152**" should be selected. If the key does not exist, either null or empty string is selected, both are acceptable.

How to acheive this, if possible, with one single select query?

Comment: Will SRID always follow a `-`? Will `Type` and `WIOD` always exist? Cn a value ever contain a `-`? Please post some more examples of all the different cases.The trick is not finding the data, it's covering all the edge cases

Comment: Fix your data structure if you can.  This is definitely not a convenient way to store data in a SQL database.

Comment: Have you considered mangling the string into XML and performing a query thereon?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The Key=Value pair can be of any order, so SRID can be the first one in the string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know...it is legacy one and I am trying to do some data patching on it without permission on changing it...

Comment: @HABO oh no I didn't think about that, what I tried is to use a mixture of PATINDEX, SUBSTRING, CASE WHEN, which is disgusting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just about any parser will do

**Option 1: with UDF**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,YourCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Type=A-SRID=152-WOID=3')


Select A.ID
      ,Item  = left(B.RetVal,charindex('=',B.RetVal+'=')-1)
      ,Value = substring(B.RetVal,charindex('=',B.RetVal+'=')+1,len(B.RetVal))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.YourCol,'-') B
 --Where B.RetVal like 'SRID%'
```

**Option 2: Without a UDF**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Item  = left(B.RetVal,charindex('=',B.RetVal+'=')-1)
      ,Value = substring(B.RetVal,charindex('=',B.RetVal+'=')+1,len(B.RetVal))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.YourCol,'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
  --Where B.RetVal like 'SRID%'
```

**Both Return**

```
ID  Item    Value
1   Type    A
1   SRID    152
1   WOID    3
```

**The UDF if Needed**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
--Performance On a 5,000 random sample -8K 77.8ms, -1M 79ms (+1.16), -- 91.66ms (+13.8)
```

Comment: Option 2 works for me, though it's too complicated for me...will try to understand it

Comment: @shole Same code as in the UDF, the XML parser is surprisingly fast.  On a 5,000 row sample only 13 ms slower than the tally parse.  Tally can not be slipped into a Cross Apply and is limited to 8K bytes.   Just think of a Cross Apply as a sub-routine.   cheers :)

Comment: @shole just an after thought.   OUTER APPLY will show null records if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who has said the edge cases are the trick is correct, but if the structure is consistent this should work as well with simple string functions. Example with three tests:

```
declare @test varchar(max) = 'Type=A-SRID=152-WOID=3'
declare @test2 varchar(max) = 'SRID=152-WOID=3'
declare @test3 varchar(max) = 'Type=A-WOID=3'

select iif(charindex('SRID=', @test) > 0, substring(@test, charindex('SRID=', @test)+5, charindex('-',substring(@test, charindex('SRID=', @test)+5, 8000))-1),'')
select iif(charindex('SRID=', @test2) > 0, substring(@test2, charindex('SRID=', @test2)+5, charindex('-',substring(@test2, charindex('SRID=', @test2)+5, 8000))-1),'')
select iif(charindex('SRID=', @test3) > 0, substring(@test3, charindex('SRID=', @test3)+5, charindex('-',substring(@test3, charindex('SRID=', @test3)+5, 8000))-1),'')
```

Edit: you are correct you need handling for if the string ends after the value you are looking for, but in that case a simple case statement will handle it. It can still be done with string functions:

```
select case when charindex('-',substring(@test, charindex('SRID=', @test)+5, 8000))-1 < 0
        then substring(@test, charindex('SRID=', @test)+5, 8000)
        else iif(charindex('SRID=', @test) > 0, substring(@test, charindex('SRID=', @test)+5, charindex('-',substring(@test, charindex('SRID=', @test)+5, 8000))-1),'')
        end
```

Comment: This fails if string is simply "SRID=152"